# Trying to Performance test an application developed in OJET technology. Which tool/protocol should I use for scripting?

Tags: jmeter, protocols, performance-testing, loadrunner

Trying to Performance test an application developed in OJET technology. Which tool/protocol should I use for scripting? I tried HTTP/Web protocol with Jmeter and Load Runner. But that doesn't capture all the requests and responses at the javascript/browser level. Hence I am facing issues in correlating the dynamic values during test design. Hence, scripts fail during the replay. Currently trying to do it with Truclient Web protocol as an alternative. But I need to know which tool/protocol should I use for scripting?

Answer (score 0):

According to [OJET](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/index.html?ojr=getstarted) looks like this is a web app generator.

1. If you choose to start with JMeter use post-processor such as regex to catch and save every value that is needed for as arg in the next request.
2. Don't be afraid of these dynamic values. Try to follow next articles to get the idea.
3. None of tools will provide you automatic correlation without issue. Nor LoadRunner, nor Jmeter. It is always tricky.
4. Ask more specific questions when you start facing issue.

[Jmeter catch correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement real user using your application with 100% accuracy in terms of network footprint

Both JMeter and/or LoadRunner are not capable of executing client-side JavaScript, the options are in:

1. Implement these JavaScript-driven network calls using scripting (in JMeter it will be [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223))
2. Use a real browser, LoadRunner's Truclient protocol is basically a [headless web browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser), in JMeter can be integrated with Selenium browser automation framework via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered/)

With regards to "which protocol/tool" to use:

1. Implementing JavaScript calls manually will take extra effort, however your test will consume less resources (CPU, RAM, etc.)
2. Using real browsers will take less efforts, but the test will consume **much more** resources (something like 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM per user/ browser instance) and you won't have metrics like Connect Time, Latency, etc.

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner TruClient.  This will handle all of the Javascript executions and dynamic elements related to session, state, date/time, object identifiers, ...   You will still need to appropriately handle user input items.